# How To get all variables incuding space & character in page url php

Tags: php, get

In my localhost url I have something like this

> **http://localhost:8080/shopping/search.php?qry=Mobiles%20&%20Tablets**

and i want to grab all the value of the variable ***qry*** using **$_GET['qry']**

but anytime i use the get method to do it, it only returns **Mobiles** not **Mobiles & Tablets**

please how do i go about it

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['qry'])) {

    echo $_GET['qry'];

} else {

    echo "";

} 

?>
```

Comment: How did the ampersand end up not being encoded as `%26`?

Comment: @mario i don't really know